# App Crashed when coming from background to foreground

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I have the following problem when my app resumes from background in iOS:
If the connection to the internet is 3G or WIFI everything works fine. If there is no data connection (nor Wifi, nor mobile) everything is fine as well.

But: If there is a bad mobile connection but Ti.Network.online still returns true, or if there is a WIFI connection without internet access, the app "hangs" after resume and finally crashes. In the device log, I get "failed to resume in time".
This happens even if I never add a "resume" event listener.

Please suggest me on this.

Here is the code:-

```
self.expirationHandler = 
^{
     [app endBackgroundTask:self.bgTask];
      self.bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
      self.bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:self.expirationHandler];
      DLog(@"Expired");
      self.jobExpired = YES;
      while(self.jobExpired)
 {
            DLog(@"Spin the While loop to run the app in infinite");

 }
        // Restart the background task so we can run forever.
        [self runtheApp:nil];
    };
    self.bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:expirationHandler];

    [self startLoggerInBackground];
}
```

Comment: Please ensure the code, you are calling in the application-resume block should not hold the thread. perhaps your call take to much time. could you post some code from the `AppDelegate`, so i can have a look into details.

Comment: poellath : i have added the code

Comment: why do you hack the lifecycle like this? the `UIApplicationDelegate` Protocol gives you multible points of action like `applicationDidBecomeActive:`, `applicationWillResignActive:`, 
`applicationDidEnterBackground:` and `applicationWillEnterForeground:`.

Comment: poellath :- code is already written in one of the delegate

Comment: So, why you are using an infinite loop, instead of waiting for the delegate call?